# PromiseKit Cannot assign value of type '[Result<TYPE>]' to type '[TYPE]

Tags: swift, promisekit

Using [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit), I am trying to set the output of the `when` block to the local variable `allChatRooms`

```
var allChatRooms : [ChatRoom]
var chatRoomIDs : [String:Bool] = ...
 firstly {

        when(resolved: chatRoomIDs.map{fetchChatRoom(id: $0.key)})

    }.then { chatRooms -> Void in

         allChatRooms = chatRooms <-- Error here

    }
```

The complier error is:

[image]
Note: (`ChatRoom` and `KChatRoom` are the same)

How can I set the result to the `allChatRooms` variable?

Comment: Vote for the question related to my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple, I mistyped the `when` block. Instead, it should be `fulfilled` instead of `resolved`

`when(fulfilled: chatRoomIDs.map{fetchChatRoom(id: $0.key)})`